# Disable iOS 12 strong password on a web app password form

Tags: javascript, angular, web, mobile-safari, ios12

Since the release of iOS 12, Apple's opinion of what a [strong password](https://www.apple.com/ios/ios-12/) is violates the back end rules my company defines as an acceptable strong password.

**As a web developer, I cannot:**

- Change how the back-end defines the password management rules (e.g.
  minimum characters, acceptable characters, etc.)
- Tell the customer to simply just disable or opt out of that iOS feature.

**Quick background of my web app's password form:**

- Written in Angular 4.
- Has the `pattern` attribute for input type password.
- Has the `required` attribute for input type password.
- Has the `minlength` attribute for input type password.

I was hoping for a quick win like a meta tag exclusive to this problem but could not find one. If you have an alternative JavaScript approach for handling this, please share.

Comment: What's the problem? Surely if the user wants to use Apple's opinion of a strong password that won't cause problems?

Comment: You'd have to change the type of the input to not be `password`, clearly something that is not in anyone's best interest. You should go to the product team and tell them you are losing customers, and make them tell the backend team to allow stronger passwords (really the only requirement you should ever have on a password is length, and maybe prevent known cracked passwords, but nothing else).